# Converting polynomial linear mapping to a linear matrix mapping

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

If you consider a *linear* map $f : \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ given by
$$
f(x, y) = (2x, 3y, x + y)
$$
Which can be represented like so:
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
  2 & 0 \\
  0 & 3 \\
  1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  x \\
  y
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where it is super intuitive that we are multiplying rows by columns, thats how we can find the polynomial version of matrix multiplication.

How can I interpret the presence of powers in a linear mapping in this example? $f : P_3(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ defined by:
$$
f(a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a+d \\
b+c
\end{bmatrix}
$$

is there a way for me to convert it into matrix polynomial function (like above the notation is interchangeable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, a matrix representation depends on the bases chosen for $P_3(\mathbf R)$ and $\mathbf R^2$. For both vector spaces, I suppose they're the canonical basis of each:
$$(1, x,x^2,x^3)\quad\text{and}\quad e_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}, e_2=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$
W.r.t. these bases, the columns of the matrix are the coordinates  of the images of the vectors in basis $(1, x,x^2,x^3)$:
$$ A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&1\\0&1&1&0\end{bmatrix} .$$

Comment: Oh, this makes sense. So if i knew the bases i could use vectors in those to represent my matrix?

Comment: Yes, the matrix af a linear map is always relative to a choice of bases of the domain and the codomain.